# Java/Mongodb authentication

Tags: java, mongodb, authentication, mule

I saw a lot of tutorials showing how to auth in mongodb using Java

I have my mongodb configured with auth enabled.
In console I use

> use admin
>
> db.auth("myUser","newPassword") and works well.

and in java In every sites visited the code is

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("myBase");

boolean auth = db.authenticate("myUser", "newPassword".toCharArray());
    //auth is true if everithing went well
```

The BIG problem is that code doesn't work for me and I don't know why. I tested changing explicitly to admin database.

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("admin");

boolean auth = db.authenticate("myUser", "newPassword".toCharArray());
DB db = mongo.getDB("myBase");
    //auth is true if everithing went well
```

This works BUT for me it is not a solution because I triying to use mongo with mule and the problem is that I can't be changing between db's for each auth which I must do.

WHY the first code works for all the people instead of me?

I realized what is the problem.

It seems that mongo work using user for each DB stored in the DB itself. I created the user in the same db and it works. It a very weird feature because I will have a lot of duplicated users in mongo, one for each DB that I have. Minus one for user managing in Mongo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized what is the problem.

It seems that mongo work using user for each DB stored in the DB itself. I created the user in the same db and it works. It a very weird feature because I will have a lot of duplicated users in mongo, one for each DB that I have. Minus one for user managing in Mongo...

Comment: I was going to mention that possibility so I'm glad you found it.  2.6 is reworking auth a fair bit so it might not hurt to look at those upcoming changes.

Answer (score 0):

That method is now deprecated.  The new, preferred way is to us [MongoClient(List<ServerAddress> seeds,
           List<MongoCredential> credentialsList)](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.11.4/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html#MongoClient%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29) to create a client which will authenticate all connections to server

Comment: I don't think that would be the problem, because I'm using mule and internally it uses db.authenticate(username, password.toCharArray())

check

https://github.com/mulesoft/mongo-connector/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mule/module/mongo/MongoCloudConnector.java

line 1257

Comment: Maybe could be a mongo config issue?

Comment: an error added but it isn't very important if you read carefully what is the issue